# PHP AJAX call not retrieving anything

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to retrieve HTML and display it on the page, it doesn't seem to retrieve anything...

My Controller script:

```
function index()
{   
    $this->load->view('ajax_post');
}

public function ajaxify()
{
    $message = "<b>hello</b>";
    echo $message;
}
```

My javascript code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").click( 
    function(){

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/index.php/ajax_post/ajaxify",
        dataType: "html",
        cache:false,
        success: 
          function(data){
            $("#content").append(html); 
          }

        });

      return false;

    });


});
```

any help would be appreciated, as I'm an absolute beginner with jQuery/AJAX

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `$("#content").html(data);` ?

Comment: you have problem with you `url` property I think

Comment: is any problem related to url???

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is built wrong; if you see the NET console in Firebug it would show 404 (or 500). Use the helper function in CI (url helper):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('ajax_post/ajaxify');?>",
    dataType: "html",
```

or build it manually including the domain name:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php/ajax_post/ajaxify",
    dataType: "html",
```

Be sure the url maps to the correct controller/method (ajax_post.php controller, ajaxify method if no custom route is assigned)

Sidenote, `append()` appends to the end of the selected element, if you want to insert *inside* an element use `$(selector).html(data);` instead

Answer (score 2):

Your Ajax success handler function:

```
function(data){
    $("#content").append(html); 
}
```

Has a parameter named `data` but then you try to append a nonexistent variable `html` Try changing it to:

```
    $("#content").append(data);
```